# Firmware update on Dell Precision 5510 fails

Tags: 20.04, kubuntu, firmware, fwupd

Previous firmware updates have worked, but this latest one (1.17.0) is giving me issues.

In Discover, it first shows me a message about a checksum failure, but doesn't crash. Available updates includes "Dell Inc. System Firmware" version 1.17.0. Current version is 1.16.1.

When I try to update it, another popup says "No supported device found" and the update remains in the list of available updates.

On the command line, it says "1 local device supported", but when attempting to update it says "No supported devices found".

I've tried removing the `~/.cache/fwupd` dir. Also tried sudo and running as root with the same results.

```
$ fwupdmgr --force -v refresh
(fwupdmgr:267206): GLib-DEBUG: 12:24:30.797: setenv()/putenv() are not thread-safe and should not be used after threads are created
(fwupdmgr:267206): Fwupd-DEBUG: 12:24:30.812: Emitting ::status-changed() [idle]
Updating lvfs
(fwupdmgr:267206): Fwupd-DEBUG: 12:24:30.816: downloading https://cdn.fwupd.org/downloads/firmware.xml.gz.jcat
(fwupdmgr:267206): Fwupd-DEBUG: 12:24:30.816: Emitting ::status-changed() [downloading]
Downloading…             [ -                                     ](fwupdmgr:267206): Fwupd-DEBUG: 12:24:31.061: download progress: 100%
(fwupdmgr:267206): Fwupd-DEBUG: 12:24:31.061: download progress: 100%
(fwupdmgr:267206): Fwupd-DEBUG: 12:24:31.061: download progress: 100%
(fwupdmgr:267206): Fwupd-DEBUG: 12:24:31.062: download progress: 100%
(fwupdmgr:267206): Fwupd-DEBUG: 12:24:31.062: Emitting ::status-changed() [idle]
Downloading…             [***************************************]
(fwupdmgr:267206): Fwupd-DEBUG: 12:24:31.063: changing metadata URI from https://cdn.fwupd.org/downloads/firmware.xml.gz to https://cdn.fwupd.org/downloads/firmware-02119-stable.xml.gz
(fwupdmgr:267206): Fwupd-DEBUG: 12:24:31.064: metadata signature of lvfs is unchanged, skipping
Successfully downloaded new metadata: 1 local device supported
```

```
$ fwupdmgr -v update
(fwupdmgr:267563): GLib-DEBUG: 12:29:39.452: setenv()/putenv() are not thread-safe and should not be used after threads are created
(fwupdmgr:267563): Fwupd-DEBUG: 12:29:39.463: Emitting ::status-changed() [idle]
Devices with no available firmware updates: 
 • Dell D3100 USB3.0 Dock
 • Dell D3100 USB3.0 Dock
 • THNSN51T02DU7 NVMe TOSHIBA 1024GB
 • UEFI dbx
 • USB3.0 Hub
 • USB3.0 Hub
Upgrade available for System Firmware from 1.16.1 to 1.17.0
Precision 5510 must remain plugged into a power source for the duration of the update to avoid damage. Continue with update? [Y|n]: y
[...]
(fwupdmgr:267563): Fwupd-DEBUG: 12:30:18.183: download progress: 100%
(fwupdmgr:267563): Fwupd-DEBUG: 12:30:18.183: Emitting ::status-changed() [idle]
Downloading…             [***************************************]
(fwupdmgr:267563): Fwupd-DEBUG: 12:30:18.288: Emitting ::status-changed() [decompressing]
Decompressing…           [***************************************](fwupdmgr:267563): Fwupd-DEBUG: 12:30:18.592: Emitting ::status-changed() [idle]
Decompressing…           [***************************************]
No supported devices found
```

Edit: I also tried `apt purge fwupd`, removing all related directories, and reinstalling. Then I tried the same thing, but installing via `snap`. Same results, slightly different UX due to the snap version being more current (1.6.2 vs. 1.5.10).

Comment: Have you upgraded this firmware before? There was a recent change to how Dell system firmware is updated due to a security fix.

Comment: @galexite Yes, I've upgraded this a couple of times before, using Discover.

Comment: I had the same problem so I ended up flashing it via the One-Time Boot Menu reached by spamming F12 on boot. From there, you have an option to flash the BIOS. This built-in tool can extract and flash the BIOS update from the downloadable Windows executable (Precision_5510_1.17.0.exe in this case) that you put on a FAT32 formatted USB stick.

I have a feeling that the issue might be due to incorrect metadata in the firmware cab file that gets downloaded.

Comment: @blunden I didn't get this solved, but I was able to flash the BIOS with the downloaded Windows executable. Incidentally, I didn't feel like searching for a USB stick so I just copied the file into the `/boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/fw/` directory, which I was able to select from that boot menu. So no need for a FAT32 USB stick!

Comment: @klugerama I'm glad that worked. Good to know it's possible without a USB stick too. :)